# Smallest (laser) holes in hardware stores for eclipse viewing

Tags: metal, hardware

Needless to say: this is a question that can best be answered by the crowd in the group, who are regular shoppers at hardware stores.

I'd like to view and show the upcoming solar eclipse. I do not wish to view it with protective gear—only through a projection.

The hardware stores nearby sell various pre-drilled metal parts.

What is the smallest, most accurate hole, I can find at a hardware store?

Ideally it would be drilled by laser and have a perfectly circular boundary.

Comment: If your objective is the sharpest image, smaller is better only to a point, then diffraction makes the image worse with decreasing hole size. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinhole_camera#Selection_of_pinhole_size

Comment: It is not safe to directly view an eclipse of the sun through a small orifice unless you have an expert opinion on your exact arrangement.

Comment: VTC as off-topic since it's a product recommendation. If you want to know what is the smallest, most accurate hole you can find at your hardware store, you should go to your hardware store and ask them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution may be easier than you think. Ordinary aluminum foil can be used as the membrane, mounted in any sort of frame from cardboard to titanium (a bit ridiculous, that). The aperture can be created to be nearly microscopic by using an ordinary straight pin. The key aspect of this creation is the backing surface on which you hammer/tap/force the pin through the foil.

If the backing is a piece of solid aluminum, you may get a bit of a bump in the  foil before the pin pierces it, but it will be quite small. You're in a good situation in that the sun will be shining every day, perhaps even where you are located and you can project the sun with your attempts.

If the backing is a piece of steel, you'll get zero bump in the foil and possibly the smallest aperture possible. Too much force may mushroom the pin tip, too little force will not create an opening.

Be sure to prevent skidding of the pin on the surface, by holding the pin perpendicular to the surface.

As noted in Phil Frost's link, too small will be problematic, but that's a good direction to have a failure. It's easier to make the hole larger, but not so easy to make it smaller.

The link noted suggests sanding down a soft drink can, but ordinary household aluminum foil will provide the thinnest possible material.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of small drill bits available out there. Can you just drill something yourself? That way, you could be sure to drill something that was the right size/configuration for whatever your mount will be.